# Best way to implement ban system for rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authentication, devise

I'm using Devise with cancan for authentication in my rails app and I'd like to be able to block certain accounts and prevent users from registering with a blocked email and phone. I'm just not sure what the best way for this.

I have roles: admin, moderator, and user
admin: must have ability to ban/block moderators, and users
moderator: must have ability to ban/block users

My first thought was to add new 'blocked' role, but I think that there is a better way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would go the simplest way : just get a boolean "blocked" on your User table. Then define something like :

```
class User 
  def block(other_user)
    if(can_block? other_user)
      other_user.block = true
      other_user.save!
    end
  end

  def can_block?(other_user)
    # Your logic using the roles.
  end
end
```

Straightforward, but I like it that way.